# Using data generated in a list from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, list, html-select

I'm newbie in PHP and would like to inquire about how can i reuse the data fetched from mysql into a list

This is the code that im using :

```
    <form method="post" action="senddata.php">
 Page Name :<select name="pages"id="list">
             <option value="0">Choose</option>
           <?php  
              $result = mysql_query("select * from menu where id>3",$connection);
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';

              }     
            ?>

          </select>
```

so when i will submit the form the selected element in the drop down list will be submitted too

Comment: What do you mean by reuse ?? Sorry , can you say it in a lil' brief

Comment: You didn't mention issue you face in the above code.

Comment: I have no problem with the provided code, i meant by reuse is this : " After i have fetched the data into the drop list, and the user choose the option there is a form needs to be submitted, for which the data will be used again but in the case of the drop down list i don't know how can i retrieve this data from the list because its retrieved from the database  in order to use it again

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, and hasn't been recommended for use for several years.  Whatever site taught you to use it, is a steaming pile of crap.  Learn about mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch all data into a array like this

```
$arr_menu = array(); 
$result = mysql_query("select * from menu where id>3",$connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr_menu[] = $row['name'];
}
```

now use this array where ever you want like this `foreach`

```
 <form method="post" action="senddata.php">
 Page Name :<select name="pages"id="list">
             <option value="0">Choose</option>
           <?php  
              foreach($arr_menu as $menu_name)
              {
                 echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';

              }     
            ?>

      </select>
```

Comment: Oh, but when i put it in an array, and the selection has been made, where is the variable that contains the chosen data?

Comment: in `$menu_name` you can iterate it in option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dataArr = array();
$result = mysql_query("select * from menu where id>3",$connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($dataArr,$row);
}        
 ?>
```

You can use the Array $dataArr whenever u need.

```
Page Name :<select name="pages"id="list">
<option value="0">Choose</option>                     
    <?php
        foreach($dataArr as $rowData){
            echo '<option value="'.$rowData['name'].'">'.$rowData['name'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</option>
```

Comment: And after selection has been made by the user where or how can i get the selected data ?

Comment: You can use `$_REQUEST['pages']` in the server side , will give you the selected dropdown value.

OR

`var listId = $('#list').val(); ` 

in the Client Side (Jquery).

Comment: Oh so it made through jquery not purely PHP